# How to have two accordion collapse with bootstrap accordion

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-accordion

I am using bootstrap accordion and want to two collapse-able div for one accordion button.

The problem is that bootstrap using id's and two same id's cannot come on the same page.

The challenge for me is that the collapse-able div does not fall under the same parent as well

```
<div class="left-col">
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                Title 1
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Content 1
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                Title 2
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Content 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                Title 3
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Content 3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="right-col">
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingOne">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                    Title 1
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingOne">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Content 1
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingTwo">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                    Title 2
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingTwo">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Content 2
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab" id="headingThree">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a class="collapsed" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
                    Title 3
                </a>
            </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="headingThree">
            <div class="panel-body">
                Content 3
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can cause the accordion to collapse with JavaScript. Give them both a shared class and use some click then collapse logic like this.

```
$('#button_to_trigger_collapse').click(function(){
    $('.div_to_collapse').collapse('toggle');
});
```

See the documentation here for more information on how to refine the behavior.

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#via-javascript-3

Comment: This just collapses the accordion if it is open. Does not open it on another click. Also, if there are 6 pairs of collapse-able content, I'll need to write the script with 6 different classes and ids

Comment: @StacyJ Your question did not specify open them back up. As I said, you can see the documentation linked, specifically the toggle functionality. And yes, you'll need to do this for every pair, bootstrap needs some way to know what behavior you're looking for, and what you're looking for isn't just supported with classes and data attributes.

Comment: @StacyJ I updated the answer to use the toggle flag, I believe that'll give you the behavior you're currently requesting.